# How to prevent bare windows in Firefox and related browsers?

Tags: firefox, javascript, links

Some websites like to use JavaScript links that open a new window, which lacks any UI except for the address bar. Meaning no extension buttons, search bar, home/back/etc. buttons, bookmarks, tab bar and so on. Opening the link in a new tab/window does not work because the JS fails to work properly.

I encountered this behavior on a private site so I can't link to an example, but if you know one please let me know and I will add it here.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, and force every window created by JS to have the full interface of a normal Firefox window? Is there a way to get controls back? I believe Chrome for instance has a menu command for it, but I'm not sure about FF.

NB: I am actually on Waterfox but let's answer for Firefox and hopefully it will apply to the forks as well.

Comment: I formerly used Waterfox also, but switched when Mozilla finally released their own 64-bit version of Firefox.  Is there a compelling reason why you haven't switched, too?

Comment: I've done this in the past but I'm having trouble figuring out what I did. This was quite a few years ago. Also Waterfox > Firefox. That's why. :)

Comment: *"Also Waterfox > Firefox. That's why. :)"*  @music2myear I always appreciate your feedback, but as you might imagine I was hoping to get a more in-depth explanation than what I might typically hear on Xbox Live.  ;-)

Comment: Waterfox began as a 64bit native version of Firefox with some of the increasing number of "user friendly" restrictions removed and a lot of the privacy settings enhanced. When Firefox went through its major change earlier this year Waterfox forked entirely and is basically a privacy-enhanced variant of the old Firefox architecture. It still supports the old plugins and is taking increasing steps towards recreating the plugin ecosystems being removed by Mozilla.

Comment: That certainly makes sense.  Typically, I use a minimal number of extensions and each one of them was migrated to the new format after Firefox 57 (a.k.a. Quantum) was released.

Comment: Yes, that is increasingly a draw-back with Waterfox.

Comment: @Run5k I just enjoy being unique I guess ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prevent_websites_from_disabling_new_window_features

In `about:config` find `dom.disable_window_open_feature.*`

There are quite a few entries here that correspond to the various features that can be disabled/manipulated. Here's the list:

- **close**: Prevents the close button from being disabled.
- **directories**: Prevents the bookmarks toolbar from being hidden.
- **location**: Prevents the address bar from being hidden
- **menubar**: Prevents the menubar from being hidden.
- **minimizable**: Prevents popup window minimization from being disabled.
- **personalbar**: Prevents the bookmarks toolbar from being hidden.
- **resizable**: Prevents popup window resizing from being disabled.
- **scrollbars**: Prevents the scrollbars on a popup from being disabled.
- **status**: Prevents the status bar from being hidden.
- **titlebar**: Prevents the title bar from being hidden.
- **toolbar**: Prevents the navigation toolbar from being hidden.

Setting these to **true** overrides the developers preferences.

Answer (score 6):

Mozilla's online documenation for the `Window.open()` web API describes how to make changes within the `about:config` Firefox management interface that will help accomplish what you want:

> **menubar**: Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows
>   to always render the menubar by setting
>   **dom.disable_window_open_feature.menubar** to
>   *true*
>
> **toolbar**: If this feature is on, then the new secondary window renders the Navigation Toolbar (Back, Forward, Reload, Stop buttons).
>   Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always render the
>   Navigation Toolbar by setting
>   **dom.disable_window_open_feature.toolbar** to *true*
>
> **personalbar**: Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always render the Personal Toolbar/Bookmarks toolbar by **setting
>   dom.disable_window_open_feature.personalbar** to *true*
>
> **titlebar**: Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always render the titlebar by setting
>   **dom.disable_window_open_feature.titlebar** to *true*
>
> **close**: Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always have a close button by setting
>   **dom.disable_window_open_feature.close** to *true*

Notably, the following preference settings already default to *true* and don't need to be changed:

**dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable**

**dom.disable_window_open_feature.location**

Also, starting with Firefox 49 the following feature is on by default so the `about:config` preference has been removed:

**dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars**

---

Source:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open